# openCV homography output mask value used as inliers on perspective error?

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, homography

For object recognition/detection in order to find good matches I used the following method.

Here I find homography two times, from first homography use output mask as filter for finding input keypoints for second homography.

I am using the features descriptor and extractor options as shown below

```
FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);
DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);


matcher.match(descriptorRef, descriptor, matches); 
List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();

keypoints_RefList = keypointsRef.toList();
keypoints_List = keypoints.toList();
```

first calculation - use all keypoints from matches

```
    ///////// first calculation
for (int i = 0; i < matchesList.size(); i++) {
    objList1.addLast(keypoints_RefList.get(matchesList.get(i).queryIdx));
    sceneList1.addLast(keypoints_List.get(matchesList.get(i).trainIdx));
}                 

obj1.fromList(objList1);    
scene1.fromList(sceneList1);

Mat hg1 = Calib3d.findHomography(obj1, scene1, 8, 10,  mask1);
```

second calculation - use only inlier keypoints from matches using mask values of mask1

```
///////// second calculation        
for(int i=0; i < mask1.rows(); i++){
    if(mask1.get(i,0)[0] == 1){   ////////this time add only where mask1 is 1
        objList.addLast(keypoints_RefList.get(matchesList.get(i).queryIdx));
        sceneList.addLast(keypoints_List.get(matchesList.get(i).trainIdx));
    }
}

obj.fromList(objList);  
scene.fromList(sceneList);

Mat hg = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene, 8, 10,  mask);
```

Now mask1 and mask are

```
mask1 : [0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 1; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 0]
mask : [0; 1; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1]
```

Now since all the input to second homography are inliers, mask value should all be 1 but its never all 1. some times i get even more zeros in mask.

The homography 3x3 output hg1 and hg has some negative values is it acceptable or what might be wrong?

What method should I use to filter good keypoints so that I get correct homography matrix and that the perspective projection is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Without proper understanding of the application and the images you are working with it is hard to tell (for instance, does homography even apply in your situation).

Nevertheless, have you experimented with RANSAC. All your feature matches may not be correct, there could be lot of noisy matches that are making your homography estimation incorrect.

Comment: well for one there isn't any useful/clear documentation for these stuff and the homography applies to all output from camera frame in android device, the problem is homography matrix is used to find perspective transform so the lines drawn with these are almost random quadrilaterals with no connection to the reference image. Now are there really any ways to find correct matches from incorrect ones or remove noises. Are there any books, documents as i wish to learn more.

Comment: Yes, there is a standard approach to remove incorrect matches using RANSAC <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC>. At the bottom of the wikipedia page, you will see also a link to C++ and Matlab implementations. I suggest you try that.